# add a view in UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I have created an UIView which has several controllers , is there any possible way to add this view in `UIPopoverController` because UIPopoverController just support ViewController !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a UIViewController and assign your UIView to be it's .view property. Then you can pass it along to the UIPopoverController while creating it.

Comment: yeah but in this way I have to create several properties to trigger the actions and etc  ...

Comment: If the actions are defined in the UIView alone, something is wrong with your MVC. The proper way to do this is divide your code so that controllers handle actions and such while the view only notifies the controller of UI events and such.

Comment: I did what you said , like this :
`- (void)viewDidLoad
{[self.view addSubview:mainViewController.fontSizeView];}` but actually nothing will be added !

Comment: Sorry but in order for me to help you I'm going to need more code. I really don't understand your class structure.